# Kendo UI Grid incell edit with client template - Razor view

Tags: kendo-ui

i am using kendo grid Q2 2014 and i want to use client template in cell edit mode. But it not work as i want . I need to click into that cell in order to get into edit mode.
Here is my grid .

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AdminProject.Common.ViewModels.ProjectActivityViewModel>()
                  .Name("gridName")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(d => d.ResourceName);
                      columns.Bound(d => d.TotalHours).Title("Total Hours").Width(150).ClientFooterTemplate("Sum: #=sum#");
                      columns.Bound(d => d.TotalCost).Title("Total Cost").Format("{0:c0}").Width(150).ClientFooterTemplate("Sum: #= kendo.toString(sum, 'c0')#");
                      columns.Bound(d => d.Hours)
                          .ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("NewHours").ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString());


                  })
                  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                  {
                      toolbar.Save(); // The "save" command saves the changed data items
                  })
                 .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                        .Refresh(true)
                        .PageSizes(true)
                        .ButtonCount(5)
                        )
                .Sortable()
                .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
                .AutoBind(true)
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Batch(true)
                .PageSize(10)
                        .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                            {
                                aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalHours).Sum();
                                aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalCost).Sum();
                            })
                .Events(events => { events.Error("error_handler").Sync("sync_handler"); })
                .ServerOperation(true)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(product => product.ResourceId); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                    model.Field(product => product.TotalHours).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(product => product.TotalCost).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(product => product.ResourceName).Editable(false);
                })
                .Read(read => read.Action(AdminProject.Common.Constants.ActionNames.GetDetail, AdminProject.Common.Constants.ControllerNames.Project).Data("additionalData"))
                .Update(update => update.Action(AdminProject.Common.Constants.ActionNames.UpdateActivity, AdminProject.Common.Constants.ControllerNames.Project).Data("additionalData2"))
                        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(s => s.ResourceId).Ascending())
                        ))
```

Sorry , i can not post the photo so i uploaded it into another host .

Before [enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/44ikjewvt/)

After [enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/9di6v14op/)

Comment: Sorry i can't get your point, means what you exctly want?

Comment: you want to click on cell and only that clicked cell will be in editable mode or whole column's(Hours as per image) all cell will be editable?

Comment: Sorry i didnt explain well. My situation is : I want to update the grid as picture "Before" show. But when i enter the value in and click Save , it does not work. I have to double click into Hours cell , and when it show like in picture "After" , that mean the cell is in edit mode. so the Save button will work. All i want is a small edit text box like picture "Before", and it show from beginning when grid is loaded. Users dont want to click or double click into every row when they enter data.

Answer (score 1):

have look on this http://jsfiddle.net/khNsE/70/ example.

This is kendo ui script you can use this instead of mvc wrapper.

```
var _roleDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, title: "Software Engineer" },
        { id: 2, title: "Quality Assurance Engineer" },
        { id: 3, title: "Team Lead" }
    ]
});

var _peopleDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, name: "John", roleId: 1, roleTitle: "Software Engineer" },
        { id: 2, name: "Dave", roleId: 2, roleTitle: "Quality Assurance Engineer" },
        { id: 3, name: "Aaron", roleId: 3, roleTitle: "Team Lead" }
    ]
});

var _grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: _peopleDataSource,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "name",
            title: "Name"
        },{
            field: "roleTitle",
            title: "Role",
            editor: function(container, options) {
                $("<input data-bind='value:roleTitle' />")
                  //  .attr("id", "ddl_roleTitle")
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataSource: _roleDataSource,
                        dataTextField: "title",
                        dataValueField: "title",
                        template: "<span data-id='${data.id}'>${data.title}</span>",
                        select: function(e) {
                            var id = e.item.find("span").attr("data-id");
                            var person =_grid.dataItem($(e.sender.element).closest("tr"));
                            person.roleId = id;

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $("#log")
                                    .prepend($("<div/>")
                                        .text(
                                            JSON.stringify(_grid.dataSource.data().toJSON())
                                         ).append("<br/><br/>")
                                    );
                                });
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    ],
    editable: true
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Hope this helps

Regards
vinit

Comment: Thanks Vap, but in your example , user still have to click to edit cell value. Is there anyway to open all editable cell when grid initial ?

Comment: there are 2 ways 1) you need to put edit button with inline editing it means when you click edit button all fields are in edit mode.

Comment: 2) here you need to write a custome javascript function on grid initialization and pass a column name of grid and manually make editing on field.

Comment: try to read this http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-dataBinding    document and find appropriate method....as per my suggestion try to call edit function (way 1) on cell click event by that you can preserve new value and update data.

Answer (score 0):

You may force the last Cell into edit mode through

```
var grid = $('#gridName').data('kendoGrid');
grid.editCell(grid.tbody.find('tr:eq(0) td:last'));
```

please refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/houssamk/7z0ubup7/1/

**NOTE:**
Please do not put this call inside the "edit" event handler because it will fire the edit event again. please see http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-editCell